# What are differences between linux kernel compiled for generic x86/64 vs Xeon or others

Tags: linux-kernel

In linux kernel config there is option to change CPU family, most precompiled kernels are `generic x86/64`.

I have a Xeon E3 CPU so I was wondering what would happen if I pick `Core duo/Newer Xeon` there.

What exactly are the differences here? Is there any point in compiling kernel for my CPU family, instead of generic one? Would the kernel optimized for Xeon even work on non-Xeon CPU's? Did someone ever measured some differences in performance and so on?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It will select corresponding config option (from arch/x86/Kconfig.cpu):

```
config MCORE2
     bool "Core 2/newer Xeon"
```

Generally speaking, `CONFIG_MCORE2` will enable compiler option `-mtune=core2` on 32-bit builds and `-march=core2` (it can be found in Makefiles `arch/x86/Makefile` and `arch/x86/Makefile_32.cpu`).

These options are described in GCC manual page:

> `-march=cpu-type`
>
> Generate instructions for the machine type cpu-type.  In contrast to -mtune=cpu-type, which merely tunes the generated code for the specified cpu-type, -march=cpu-type allows GCC to generate code that may not run at all on processors other than the one indicated.
>
> Specifying -march=cpu-type implies -mtune=cpu-type.
>
> **core2**
>
> Intel Core 2 CPU with 64-bit extensions, MMX, SSE, SSE2, SSE3 and SSSE3 instruction set support.

Speaking on overall effect of that compile option to application performance, it should be relatively low:

- In kernel overall architecture matters. I.e. contending lock may easily kill performance and lock-free data-structure help gain it. And they work regardless of compiler options.
- There are small number operations in kernel that require SIMD operations that are enabled by that optimization (except for copying arrays or strings probably). There are small number of CPU-intensive operations in kernel at all. But optimizations for cacheline size may work well.
- For applications that are not *kernel-bound* which are spend most of their time in userspace, rarely calling a kernel using *system calls* effect of that optimization reduced proportionally. I.e. for 2% kernel performance improvement for app that spends only 10% in kernel, you'll get only 0.2% overall performance increase.

Comment: OK, is there any significant improvement to system performance or stability when this option is used? Is it being used widely, or it's rather rarely used option? I was always thinking that kernel itself using it's own ASM code decide during boot which CPU features are available and utilize as many of them as possible (eg. some special instruction sets like MMX. SSE etc.)

Comment: @Petr: most of the kernel code is written in C. For large kernels like Linux, overall architecture matters, so performance improvement will be quite small except for some CPU-intensive algorithms like decompression or cryptography. Most Linux distros ship pre-compiled kernels with `CONFIG_GENERIC_CPU` except for probably Gentoo-like ones.

Comment: Ask yourself (or your `top` command) how much time is spend in kernel on your workload. In most cases it's very small, like couple percent. So if you will speedup your kernel code even by 50% (which is at least one order of magnitude higher that I would expect for this kind of optimization), it won't give you much performance boost overall. If, on the other hand, your workload is very unusual and you do spend most of the time in kernel space, then this might be worth considering. That being said, I don't know any benchmarks that tested that.

Comment: aha so this will speed up the kernel itself but not userspace processes running on it? I was thinking it's going to affect whole system performance, if it's just for kernel it probably doesn't matter. If that is true it's a very important fact that is missing in the answer right now.

Comment: @Petr: I've updated my answer regarding overall performance improvement.

Comment: It's interesting that if you look at the cryptography modules, there are multiple modules for the same cyphers but which indicate support for different vector instructions. Strange that this doesn't appear to be driven by the MCORE2 flag, but rather gives you the choice to explicitly choose between different implementations.